# An activity diagram can contain genaralization relationship?

Tags: uml

An activity diagram can contain generalization relationships?

what are the activity diagram holding relationships??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generalization is a relation between two classes. It does not matter in which diagram you show it.

Activity Diagrams usually contain lots of Actions which are connected with ControlFlow (or ObjectFlow) relations.

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of a place where classes occur in activity diagrams. Do you have an example?

Comment: You can put classes on an AD to refer to something as example. Usually you don't put them there. Hard to construct that "out of nothing".

Comment: Sounds reasonable.